# Architecture of web layer

Tags: model-view-controller, web, layer, n-tier-architecture

I would like to know about Architectural issues of Web Layer. I am very much confused by the TCP/IP layers, the web layer, 2 tier, 3 tier and n tier concept. Also what about MVC? Do they all mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the layer of an application that your are referring to is called the 'Presentation Layer.' This is because the user interface may not necessarily be a web client. It could be any interface.

In the n-tier architectural approach the Presentation Layer is one of the common 3 layers used, along with a Business layer and a Data layer. The presentation layer is the layer responsible for delivering the content to the user. Application logic should be handled in the business layer, and data concerns in the data layer.

MVC is a design pattern used in the presentation layer. It concerns itself solely with the presentation of data. The 'view' of MVC is your template for data, the controller is the code that addresses presentation logic, and the model is a data structure used to marshal the data between the view and the controller.

TCP/IP is related to the tiers in Networking, and are a completely separate concept from application tiers.

Comment: Totally makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

The architectural issues of the web layer are
 1. Translation
 2. Compression 
 3. Encryption